# XAMPP MySQL not starting: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 263: kill: No such process

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

When I launch XAMPP, apache works fine but mysql doesn't start, it always say:
'*Failed to start "mysql": cannot start service: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 263: kill: No such process*'
It is weird because before, everything was working great, and one time, while working on my project, I sent an sql request from php and after when I refreshed phpmyadmin, my database wouldn't show. I restarted XAMPP and mysql wouldn't start again. The sql request from php was looking like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE courses_messages SET message=? WHERE id=?;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("Location: ../error.php");
    exit();
}
else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $newQues, $quesId);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    header("Location: ../course.php?courseid=".$courseIdFromGet."&change=success".$quesId);
    exit();
}
```

I am using a MacBook Air and while this happened I was on Big Sur but just today I updated to Monterey and no difference.

Comment: Well if you are thinking this code destroyed your MySQL Server instance, it didnt

Comment: @RiggsFolly, do you know what this error mean though

Comment: Right, first look at the MySQL Error Log

Answer (score 1):

**Just try this:**

[image]

Open terminal from Xampp -> enter `apt-get update` then -> enter`apt-get install nano` then -> navigated to mysql folder `cd ../opt/lampp/var/mysql` -> delete these files `rm ib_logfile0` enter and -> `rm ib_logfile1` enter

now restart Xampp.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your mysql located at /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server ? I'm using MacOX too. If I install by default, the sql is in folder "application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin"
For me, the faster to solved the problem is backup all your files and database  and reinstall a fresh new XAMPP

Comment: ok and how do I backup my database if I can't open mysql?

Comment: may I know you cannot start mysql service or cannot connect to ?
can you access http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ ?

maybe you can search your settings with "/opt/lampp/bin" . it seems not to belong to your macbook directory path

Answer (score 0):

Type the following two commands:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

I hope it works good.

Comment: Could work, but probably not for mac.